# how to determine an application version from own application

Tags: android

IThe scenario is that my application search all installed application in order to determine versions of those applications. Then store name of the application with its versions on the same file. If new version of the application is available, then give notification to the user. The question is "how can I learn the version of the other application from my application ?"

Thanks for all your help

Comment: The play store provides the version name, not the version code, which is a String, and so it can be anything - it is not incremental. Although you can get the `versionCode` (which is an int) from your installed apps, you can't check against anything. If you use `versionName`, then you get a not-so-certain check.

Comment: Are you using Google's Play store, or your own "store"? If the former, you won't need this, as the Play store takes care of any updates. If the latter, then your store ought to implement an API returning the latest `versionCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work to get the current version:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages();

for(int i=0;i<packages.size();i++)
{
    int version = packages.get(i).versionCode;
    // do whatever with it here
}
```

Getting the most recent version in the Play Store doesn't really work, though. Like A--C said, you could check `versionName` instead, and just notify as updated if the two aren't exactly the same(don't worry about higher/lower, just inequality).

Answer (score 0):

You can do following (inside of Activity or any other Context)

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode
```